# input SharePoint calender into content editor web part

Tags: 2010, calendar, cewp

I am designing a new web part page based off the requirements presented to me.  The customer wants to have linked images to other parts of their site, but they also want their department calendar embedded between the linked images.  putting linked images into a cewp is pretty easy, but is it possible to get it so a share point calender is sitting inside the cewp?  If so, how would one go about accomplishing that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `Web Part Page` which has 3 zones.

So place the image in left zone, then calendar on middle, then image on the left zone.

Another option is to edit the page in SharePoint Designer. Place a `<table>` tag with 3 `<td>` and move the webpart code inside those.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I should have mentioned in my original post that I am already making this in a web part page. using the 3 zone template wont really work because of other design requirements.  However, can I still add a table to the webpart page? I feel like that would only be in a regular page

Comment: Yes. You can edit the page in Designer and do the magic. Also you can use `CSS` to position the image. Or user jQuery to dynamically move the objects around.

Comment: Thanks. I will be looking into this solution today, I will also mark your answer correct as it seems to be the best way to go about this.

Comment: Creating a custom page layout will let you choose the page structure/design you want. You could add tables and DIVs based on your design and hence you will be able to crate table structure, align images, and insert webpart zones with in tables to insert calendar webparts later.